# Excel - Check if value X and value Y is on the same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel document with two sheets, **data** and **edu-plan**. The sheet **data** has the following information:

[image: data]

The sheet **edu-plan** looks like this:
[image: result]

**My question is:** how do i create an excel formula that checks if the target group on the specific row in edu-plan! has the course name in question on the same row as the target group in sheet data!, i.e. if Sales and Sales course is on the same row in the sheet data!?

In reality, the **data** sheet as a couple of hundred rows and will change over time, so i am trying to develop a formula that i can apply easily on all rows/columns in edu-plan!.

The desired result in **edu-plan** would look like this: 
[image: Result]

Comment: A pivot table can easily achieve this. However instead of `x`'s you will get `1`'s (count).

Comment: How would i create such a pivot table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pivot table might be a good way to go.

If you would like to do it by formula, then you can just use a COUNTIFS

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(data!$A$2:$A$10,$A2,data!$B$2:$B$10,B$1),"X","")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to solve your issue with an array formula:
Write in B2 of sheet edu-plan

```
{=IFERROR(IF(MATCH('edu-plan'!$A2&'edu-plan'!B$1,data!$A$2:$A$6&data!$B$2:$B$6,0)>0,"x",""),"")}
```

Since it is an array formula, you need to hit `shift + ctr + enter`.

Here is the formula broken down:

`MATCH('edu-plan'!$A2&'edu-plan'!B$1,data!$A$2:$A$6&data!$B$2:$B$6,0)`
checks whether the combination of row header and column header is in the data table. `MATCH` returns the index of the found combination. Since we are not interested in the location, we only ask `IF(MATCH > 0, "x", "")` to write an "x" if a match was found. If `MATCH` finds nothing, it returns an error, which is why we add an `IFERROR(VALUE, "")` around the construct.